# My teacher says this exam Thevenin's problem is wrong

Tags: thevenin

I want you, experts, to help me here in an awkward situation. 
I have this Thevenin's exercise that I did on an exam, and my teacher gave me zero quotation, and I still don't understand why... He just says what I did isn't a Thevenin's equivalent...
In case I'm right, how could I argue with him?
In the first image, I got the original circuit. And he asks the Thevenin's circuit, from terminals A and B. 
In the second image, I opened the circuit in terminals A and B, and that resistor goes already to the equivalent circuit. Then I calculated the equivalent thevenin's resistor from terminals A and B, and then I calculated the Thevenin's tension, which will be 100V, since when I open the circuit it passes no current there, so there will be no drop of potential on any resistor.

[image: Exam problem]

Comment: I agree with your teacher.  Your equivalent circuit should have a single voltage source and a single resistor.  The voltage will ~64 volts.  You have the resistor value wrong as well.

Comment: You short A to B with an ammeter and compute the current through the ammeter, when connected like that. Then you remove the ammeter and simply use a voltmeter across A and B and read the voltage from that (circuit will have current flowing.) The voltage you read is the thevenin voltage source. The voltage you measured (which equals the thevenin voltage) divided by the current you measured, is the thevenin resistance. Your final circuit is the thevenin voltage source in series with the thevenin resistance to the terminals A and B, ***without*** the \$7\:\Omega\$ resistor across them.

Comment: @jonk what's wrong on saying when I open the circuit I have no current there, and then I put a ground referential on B, and know that on A is going to be 100V ?

Comment: What's wrong is that you ***removed*** the \$7\:\Omega\$ resistor when you "open the circuit." You open the A and B contacts to measure the voltage. However, you do NOT remove the resistor when doing that. It stays.

Comment: How would you calculate the Voltage without using the voltemeter?

I have seen a lot of videos where they insert that resistor in the equivalent circuit, removing from the original..

Comment: @jonk I understood your method, but, how can I solve it analitically?

Comment: I can't address myself to videos you've seen. Clearly, your interpretation of them into the circumstance that your teacher is asking about wasn't correct. That's neither a problem for the video (which may be correct, but where you misunderstood its application) or for your teacher (who may also be correct, but where you didn't deal with the problem correctly.) The video and your teacher can be simultaneously right. But I can't speak to the videos as I haven't seen them.

Comment: As far as showing you an analytical approach, since you exposed your thinking here I'll give it a shot for you. Hopefully, it will help out.

Comment: @jonk you can see till minute 5.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E38u3pLHSOc&t=427s

Comment: I see. That is a case where one wants to know what a load resistor "sees" looking backward into the circuit. You remove the load to do that. Are you saying that the \$7\:\Omega\$ resistor in your circuit is a load and not part of the circuit? If so, it is unusual to show the A and B terminals like that.

Comment: @jonk Thevenin's Theorem is applied when we have a very complex and hard to analyze circuit, and we will simplify it, allowing us to calculate the current that passes on our "load resistor" with one simple calculation, instead of analyzing the circuit all around again! 
I have seen the way I'm doing in several videos on internet and books. 
I think, the way you're saying, I will simply calculate the equivalent, and in the end I'll *add* a *load* that will be implemented on the circuit.

Comment: @jonk With your method, if you calculate the current that passes through the 7ohm resistor, it gives you 9A, but in the end, if you implement a load resistor of 7ohm the current there will be 6.7A, why? Because you're adding! You are adding to the circuit!
The way I do, the current on the original circuit is 9A, and in the equivalent circuit is 9A too, because I am not adding, I am keeping the same circuit! But it is useful as well, because I can simply change my load of 7ohm to other value, and it will simply give me the new current, instead of reanalyze all circuit again!

Comment: @jonk by the way, analitically, to your method result, I think you had to insert a current source of 1 A, and then your Vtest at terminals AB would be equal to equivalent Resistor from terminals A and B.. probably it would result..

Comment: @jonk I honestly think we both are right. Both ways are useful.

Comment: @VitorAguiar I've added an answer that may, or may not, help clarify things for you.

Comment: Sure, maybe both ways are useful, but only one is requested by the question. In the original circuit, you have a one-port network, and the question is to reduce that one-port network to a Thevenin equivalent. You found *a* Thevenin equivalent, but for the wrong network.

Comment: @VitorAguiar Why didn’t you ask your teacher what was wrong? Isn’t it his job to explain you your mistakes?

Comment: @andars if it asks to do a equivalent from terminals A and B, supposedly, what's inside must keep there! The 7ohm resistor must stay in the equivalent, what's left on the circuit is what must be simplified.. that's what makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Your schematic to solve is either the one on the left side (green box) or else the one on the right side (blue box) below. Starting at the top are the two possible questions being asked, with the left side being one question and the right side being the other question.

I've also included the process of going through to complete the Thevenin equivalents, as you read downward. So on the left side you see one result taking place and on the right you see a different result taking place. Both are correct. It merely depends on which one you care about.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3M8QL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the left side, you are trying to ask, "What does a known load 'see' when looking backwards into the circuit inside the green box?" This is not a normal question to ask, because usually problems like this do NOT provide you with a ***known*** load value. That's unusual for educational purposes since the Thevenin of what is inside the box doesn't depend upon the load. So why include it?

On the right side, you are trying to ask, "What does an unknown load 'see' when looking backwards into the circuit inside the blue box?" This ***is*** a normal question to ask.

But note that these are two completely different questions. So it's important to know which question is being asked.

---

The green box is analyzed a lot like you did. The Thevenin voltage is actually \$V_{TH}=100\:\textrm{V}\$. The Thevenin resistance is \$R_{TH}=\left(R_1\:\vert\vert\: R_2\right)+\left(R_3\:\vert\vert\: R_4\right)=3\frac{51}{55}\:\Omega\$. And you are done.

But now, you can see how the bottom left side answer is ***almost*** like the middle step in the right side column. Except that what was a LOAD resistance on the left side is now considered to be an internal part of the circuit on the right side. So the right side (blue box) circuit has to proceed one more step in order to complete the Thevenin equivalent, once this \$7\:\Omega\$ resistor is included. The final result is shown at the bottom, right. Here, the Thevenin voltage is \$V_{TH}=100\:\textrm{V}\cdot\frac{7\:\Omega}{7\:\Omega+3\frac{51}{55}\:\Omega}=64\frac{36}{601}\:\textrm{V}\$ and the Thevenin resistance is \$R_{TH}=7\:\Omega\:\vert\vert\:3\frac{51}{55}\:\Omega=2\frac{310}{601}\:\Omega\$.

I can't help beyond this point.

Comment: I'm not confused. The question of my teacher is simply: "get the Thevenin's equivalent", it's just that! So, both answers would be correct!

Comment: @VitorAguiar Hmm. Do you think your teacher was asking a question where there were two valid answers? Could be. But I don't buy it. More to the point, why do you think your teacher marked your answer wrong?

Comment: I understood what you did on the right part. I just don't understand why my way would be unuseful, it can be useful just like your way! I'm just saying, whatever it's inside terminals A and B, the whole circuit that has been left behind can be simplified, and I can put whatever I want inside A and B, and I will analyze it in a very easy way!

Comment: I think it's because he doesn't know this method.

Comment: @VitorAguiar Okay. That's fine. I'm honestly not trying to convince you of anything. It's your teacher, your class, your education, and your grades. That's none of my business. But the fact remains you got marked down for your answer. I'm just hoping my thoughts here help you interpret things better in the future. But only you know if it helps.

Comment: I honestly think that both ways are correct, the difference is that in yours you add a Load X, in mine, I simply change 7ohm to Xohm.

Comment: @VitorAguiar Fine. Both ways are "correct." That doesn't change the fact that a question you are given will almost certainly only have one valid answer. So. Will you be better able to anticipate the question, next time, and provide the answer they are looking for? Or will it just be a coin-flip again? I know that I'd be able to tell. I'm just wondering if you feel better able to tell, now.

Comment: @VitorAguiar I can't give you the reward you feel you deserve. That is out of my hands. If the above helps you argue with your teacher, great. Regardless, there's not much left here to chew over. We've discussed this to death and there's no further place to go.

Comment: yes, you're right. lol Thanks, anyway. You're work wasn't in vain.

Comment: @VitorAguiar Thanks for letting me know. I appreciate that.

Comment: @VitorAguiar Did this help you get your teacher to adjust your grade?

Comment: I'll talk with him next Wednesday, but I'll let you know as soon as I talk to him.

Comment: @VitorAguiar I cleaned up by answer to focus on the issues at hand and to leave out the rest. In case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

What your teacher means is that what you have done is to simplify one set of resistors but that has not created a Thevenin equivalent circuit. A Thevenin circuit is always a single voltage source in series with a single resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDrnVv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First of all I must emphasise, do not remove the 7 ohm resistor! That is crucial to the system and without it the exercise is trivial.

The Thevenin voltage is simply the voltage measured between the terminals A and B. This is usually just a case of some potential divider. This is the case in your question. So Vth is 100 * 7/(216/55 + 7).

The resistance is most easily calculated by rewriting the circuit with the voltage source as a short circuit. One way to view this is that since the voltage source has constant voltage for any current it there has very low resistance because R = ΔV/ΔI = 0. With the voltage source removed the circuit is simply the parallel resistance of the different branches between A and B.

If you want more detail please ask :)

EDIT:

I include an example of when we  might use a Thevenin equivalent to illustrate what exactly we are trying to achieve. I don't expect you to understand the operation of transistors but hopefully this might help get an intuition into why we include the 7 ohm resistor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJcWFj.png)</sup>

It is often desirable to transform one section of a large circuit to simplify analysis. In the above example we do this to avoid having to calculate the parallel current in R2 and the emitter (arrow) of the transistor. That kind of analysis is not impossible but it's messy. Essentially the objective is to remove R2. Once this is done (as in B) then the analysis becomes Kirchoff's voltage law (Voltages in a loop must sum to zero), which is very simple in this case.

If we imagine using your transform in this situation, R2 would not be removed. In fact, nothing in this circuit would change. I reiterate that I don't expect you to understand how the transistor works, just that circuit B is easier to analyse than circuit A.

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. But I don't like this method because I don't know how to work with voltage dividers, so, the way I did in my image, is the way I have seen a lot of people do, and in books too. The purposes are the same, which is, to create a simpler circuit. But if you calculate the initial current going on the 7ohm, resistor, and if you add on the terminals of your equivalent circuit the current will be different. And on my equivalent circuit they are the same.

Comment: Your circuit has the function of calculating currents on loads that you implement, mine needs only to change the value of the resistor. Both are useful, and both are right.

Comment: Well I suppose correctness all comes down to how you define the problem. I think you are misunderstanding the significance of thevenin equivalents. I haven't seen the original question but I can almost guarantee that they are not considering the 7 ohm resistor as a load. If you do consider it as a load, the question becomes a trivial simplification of the top resistor network. The reason why we use thevenin equivalents is so that we can reform a circuit into a simple voltage source with an output resistance (in other words a non ideal source).

Comment: I added an example of when we might use a thevenin equivalent so you can see why removing the 7 ohm resistor isn't a particularly helpful step.

Comment: I understand what you say. But try to understand what I say. I used my method in the example that I posted, but I've used it in circuits 10 times harder to analyze. If I got a 10 Ohm resistor between A and B, I will simplify the rest of the circuit, and I'll keep that load between A and B on the equivalent. After that, instead of a 10 Ohm resistor, it can be subsituted by a 20ohm resistor, or 100, or X, and I'll know all the parameters I want on that resistor X without reanalyzing that circuit again.

Comment: If you want I can post a lot harder example to you see. In my example here, it is simple, and it looks trivial, but it is useful in harder examples, it does the exact same thing that your method, it facilitates the analyze of a circuit, but I don't need to add something to my circuit, I just need to substitute what's inside AB. Well, thanks for this discussion. I appreciate what you did for me.

Comment: So if I were to ask you to analyze your circuit with a 10 ohm load what would you do? What would you replace the 7 ohm resistor with?

Comment: I would just remove my 7ohm resistor and put a 10ohm resistor. With this, I would discover my new current on that resistor and my new voltage between A and B. Why does it works? Because in my equivalent circuit I didn't use the 7ohm resistor in my calculations, I opened the circuit between A and B.

Comment: You see, I think the problem we're having is not about the correctness of any one step, your method is not wrong, it's just not helpful to the same extent that thevenin equivalents are. Let us call the 7 ohm resistor R1 from now. In many cases R1 will be an internal component of the circuit, and I am sure this is the case in your teacher's question. If we load terminals A and B with RL then your R1 will now appear in parallel with RL. So in my question above, if I were to use your method, I would have replaced the 7 ohm resistor with a 4 ohm resistor (7||10).

Comment: This is not too much trouble when we are just talking about resistors but when we introduce non-linear and active components like Diodes and transistors or transient behaviour of reactive components it gets trickier (though not impossible). Is this clear? Am I repeating myself?

Comment: since you understand this better than me, I invite you to give a look at "Basic Engineering Circuit Analysis" of J.David Irwin.. maybe if you understand what's there, you can tell what's failing in this discussion..

Comment: Because that was the book I used..

Answer (score 0):

Vitor, you are incorrect. What you have done is assume that the 7ohm resistor is the load when infact the load in the question is an open circuit. Now what the thevenin equivalent does is allow us to analyze quickly and effectively the current and voltage across an arbitrary load. This is not the same as replacing the 7ohm resistor as that is an internal part of the circuit that we can't modify, and our load appears in parallel to it.

Comment: I understand what you say. But why can't I modify the 7ohm resistor? On my equivalent circuit I never used on my calculations the 7 ohm resistor, so, in the end, the 7ohm resistor is Independent, of the rest of the circuit, it actually is a X resistor. Say that we got a 7ohm resistor on the original circuit and you'll analyze the original circuit, and the current on the 7ohm resistor is A. Then you'll use my equivalent and you find that the current on 7ohm resistor is A. Now do the same thing but considering a 10 Ohm resistor. It will give a B current on the original circuit, as well on the...

Comment: ... equivalent. So, in fact, it gives you the correct information that you want on the terminals of resistor X. If you would analyze the original circuit, you had so much trouble to find that current is B, whereas you could simply use my equivalent and find that current is B.

Comment: Why does several people does like this? Why does some books teach it like this as well? I'm unfornated because I choosed the wrong book then

Comment: You didn't choose the wrong book, you just aren't thinking about it quite right.

The 7ohm resistor is part of a circuit, but in general we have no idea what the circuit is. A model a lot of teachers use for thiking about this is a black box. Imagine that the circuit is in a black box that we can't see inside of, and that box has two terminals sticking out: the A and B terminals. Now what the Thevenin equivalent is, is a model we can use for modelling what is inside the box based on only what we can measure from outside the box.

Comment: (had to extend to 2 comments)
The way we do this is to measure the output voltage between the terminals, this is the Thevenin voltage. This is a simple voltage divider; you say you don't understand voltage dividers well i put it to you that they are much easier than Thevenin equivalents. Next, we short the terminals, because we want to know what is the most current that can flow if our load is a short circuit. So you short the terminals, measure the current flowing, and say 'what Thevenin resistance do i need so that my Thevenin voltage pushes this much current through a short circuit?'

Comment: Yes, I also know all you said. The only way of you can help is watching the book I used... if you want to give it a try, tell me pls.

Comment: The fact that you cannot understand what is posted here makes no sense. We have explained the concept for you 3 times, as clearly as possible. If you are too stubborn to actually read what we have written then I have no time for you.

Comment: lol I have read everything more than 1 time. And I said that I understood. I know how to do the way you are saying. I'm just saying the only way you can believe that what I'm saying is correct is reading the book.

Comment: But you are not correct. You haven't found the Thevenin Equivalent at all. All you did was simplify a couple of parallel and series resistors.